# Rep in chat > Rep on site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Not sure this is a bug or if there's a reason for it, I just noticed my rep count in chat is a bit higher than on the site, what's up with that ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add your rep across the SO world and it should be 4513

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The combined SE rep is the total rep of all SE sites that you are engaged in and has a rep of 200+. That's what's shown in chat and in the [combined flair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9551/blackbird57/flair).

Comment: All SE sites other than OS and MSE, which have their own chat systems.